# Error in DataStore2

Tags: roblox

I'm trying to make a clicker type game in roblox, although im pretty new to datastore2. I know how to use datastore but after getting just a :SetAsync() a few times a minute is too much for it as most people know. I watched an AlvinBlox tutorial on DataStore2, and have made a test with it (DataStore2 is successfully installed).

Error (also when using this the leaderstats aren't working): `Model.MainModule:566: DataStore2() API call expected {string dataStoreName, Instance player}, got {string, nil}`

Scripts

Main Script In ServerScriptService with datastore2 (i know that dnacps wont be saved as im justing using that for a test rn):

```lua
local DataStore2 = require(1936396537)
local onClick = game.ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("onClick")
local displayClicks = game.ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("displayClicks")
local default = 0
local dnapc = 1

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)

    local DNADS = DataStore2("dna",player)

    local leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder",player)
    leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"

    local dna = Instance.new("IntValue", leaderstats)
    dna.Name = "DNA"

    local function dnaUpdated(updatedVal)
        dna.Value = DNADS:Get(updatedVal)
    end

    dnaUpdated(default)

    DNADS:OnUpdate(dnaUpdated)

end)

onClick.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(val)
    local DNADS = DataStore2("dna", player)

DNADS:Increment(dnapc, default)
    displayClicks:FireClient(val)
end)
```

LocalScript (in with gui, this game is gui focused):

```lua
local onClick = game.ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("onClick")
local displayClicks = game.ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("displayClicks")

script.Parent.Activated:Connect(function()
    onClick:FireServer()
end)

displayClicks.OnClientEvent:Connect(function(val)
    script.Parent.Parent:WaitForChild("DNA").Text = "DNA: "..val
end)
```

I hope this is enough to help.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Looks like somehow your functions are getting called with a `nil` player. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: no, as i said i am new to studio sort of lol

Comment: I really dont know anything about this, but this function: `onClick.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(val) local DNADS = DataStore2("dna", player)` looks like it tries to call DataStore2() with an undefined/undeclared player variable

Comment: adding `player` before `val` returns the error `FireClient: player argument must be a Player object`

Answer (score 0):

`Player` is local because function parameters are always local. You are attempting to access it in a different function. You may want to try this:

```
[...]
local thePlayer -- thePlayer is local, however, it can be accessed in functions which are in the same script

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    thePlayer = player
    [...]
end)

onClick.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(val)
    local DNADS = DataStore2("dna", thePlayer)
    [...]
end)
```